# Why are my named capture groups not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a list of filenames representing movies. Each movie definitely has a title and a file extension, but each filename can include 0-3 tag lists. A tag list is a pair of parentheses enclosing comma-separated tags; a tag begins with `%` (for series/franchise names), `@` (for people), or `#` (for a descriptive tag), and each kind goes in their own list. They always precede the file extension, have no spaces between them, and always appear in the order `(%series,%series)(@person,@person)(#tag,tag)`. Examples:

- Casablanca.mov
- The Empire Strikes Back (%Star Wars).mov
- Return of the Jedi (%Star Wars)(@George Lucas,@Carrie Fisher).mov
- The Phantom Menace (%Star Wars,%Star Wars Prequels)(#scifi,#action).mov
- Jurassic Park (@Steven Spielberg)(#dinosaurs).mov
- Titanic (#disaster).mov

My goal is to write a regular expression with named capture groups `title`, `serieslist`, `peoplelist`, and `taglist` to help me extract all these neatly.

I can manage it when they're all present, but I'm very confused when it comes to making them optional, and it's a big unreadable expression that's tricky to parse.

Here's my best effort so far. It matches all the tag lists, and is fine when any are missing... but only if there's a space after the title. There's a space after the title match group, so that makes sense. But if I remove that space from the regex then all the other groups fail and I can't understand why. Have I overlooked something dumb? Is it a lazy/greedy thing I'm missing?

```
(?<title>.+) (?:\((?<series>%[^)]+)?\))?(?:\((?<people>@[^)]+)?\))?(?:\((?<tags>#.+)\))?(?<extension>\.[^.]+)$
```

[Here is my Regex101 page with a set of unit tests](https://regex101.com/r/reGrFk/2) on the 'switch to unit tests' tab, hopefully those make more sense than my description.

Big thanks to anyone who can help me realize my mistake.

Comment: When regex is your hammer everything looks like a thumb. (I.e., I wouldn't use regex for this--it's a mini-DSL, treat it like one.)

Comment: Your regex is correct, just make the `title` named capture group *lazy*: `(?<title>.+?)`. At the moment `title` capture group matches as much as possible (which is why putting the space stops that, because it'll match until the last space that it can since you're forcing a backtrack)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<title>.+?)[ ]*(?:\((?<series>%[^)]+)\)|\((?<people>@[^)]+)\)|\((?<tags>#[^)]+)\))*(?<extension>\.[^.]+)$
```

**[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/reGrFk/4)**

Series, people and tags capturing groups are placed into an alternation, which are then repeated to allow for flexible ordering of those 3 items. This would allow multiple tags in the name, but only the last one is captured.